# 13 days out of 15 used on Schengen Visa valid until April but want to travel in the following months

Tags: visas, schengen, malta

I have an Asian friend who is a British citizen card valid until early next year. He got a Schengen visa last October from the Maltese Embassy. 15 days until April 2013. We did not know at the time what has happened now.

He has used 13 days and booked several trips to France and Spain in the following weeks, so we thought he could go to the French embassy to sort it out. The French embassy said that because he already had a Schengen visa from Malta, they could not do anything and that he should go sort it out with the Maltese Embassy.

The Maltese Embassy have however refused to extend or cancel the visa saying they cannot cancel/revoke as the visa has already been used and that they cannot extend an existing visa until it expires! So there is no way out??

Comment: "who is a British citizen card valid until early next year" - huh? Do you mean his passport is valid until next year? British citizens don't usually need schengen visas...?

Comment: Resident card sorry!

Comment: Great - I'd suggest editing your question to clear that up :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Having more than one Schengen visa is not allowed, and extending one is impossible. Cancelling it should not be hard but bureaucracy of the embassies/consulates are a pain in the ass sometimes.

The only way to get out of this is luck, for example if the passport was accidentally clipped, or accidentally some water was spilled on it, the passport will be damaged then you can apply for a new passport and then apply for a new Schengen visa from any other EU embassy. But again, only if you are lucky ;)

Comment: You can also request a new one, usually. You can just send the old one in and get it clipped (ie officially rendered unusable).